# How to print the counting in reverse order from 10 to 1 in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I want to print reverse order of counting. How can I do that in java?
I tried a little bit code but not succeed.

```
import java.util.*;
public class reversecount 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int num;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Any Number");
        num = sc.nextInt();

        for(num=1; num<=10; num--)
        {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rethink your loop. Right now it means: reassign `num` to 1, then for every iteration `num` is less than or equal to 10, *decrease* `num`. Also, why are you reassigning `num`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start at 10 (not 1), and continue as long as the value is larger than 0:

```
for (num = 10; num > 0; num--) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making an infinite loop because num will always be smaller than 10. The value of num is decreasing with the passes of loop.

```
for (num = 10; num >= 0; num--) { 
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

This will print the array in reverse order like `10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0`

According to the comment.  Use while loop

```
while(num>=0){
      System.out.println(num);
      num--;
}
```

This will do the work for you.

Comment: I have one doubt do you want to take array as input and want to show that array reversed or anything else ?

Comment: actually that was my fault , i was thinking to make code if any user type like 20 so it would count reverse to 1 but , ok  i made it simple by giving them a value already.